# CSS Frame Generator in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, generator

I want to build something similar to [CSS Generator](http://lab.xms.pl/css-generator/). This is what I have worked on till now:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$source = '<body class="theme">
    <div class="header">
        <h1><a href="#">Welcome</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <h2>Main Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2012 Me!</p>
    </div>
</body>';
$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->loadHTML($source);
$nodes = $html->getElementsByTagName("*");
$css = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodes->item($i);
    if(!$node->hasAttribute("class") && !$node->hasAttribute("id"))
        $css = $css . str_replace(array("/"), array(" "), $node->getNodePath()) . " {}\n";
    if ($node->hasAttribute("class")) {
        $css = $css . $node->nodeName . "." . $node->getAttribute("class") . " {}\n";
    } elseif ($node->hasAttribute("id")) {
        $css = $css . "#" . $node->getAttribute("id") . " {}\n";
    }
}
echo $css;
?>
```

The output I am getting is not the right one. The desired output is:

```
body.theme div.header {}
body.theme div.header h1 {}
body.theme div.header h1 a {}
body.theme div.content {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a {}
body.theme div.content div.main {}
body.theme div.content div.main h2 {}
body.theme div.content div.main p {}
body.theme div.footer {}
body.theme div.footer p {}
```

But now I get is:

```
 html {}
body.theme {}
div.header {}
 html body div[1] h1 {}
 html body div[1] h1 a {}
div.content {}
div.sidebar {}
 html body div[2] div[1] ul {}
 html body div[2] div[1] ul li[1] {}
 html body div[2] div[1] ul li[1] a {}
 html body div[2] div[1] ul li[2] {}
 html body div[2] div[1] ul li[2] a {}
 html body div[2] div[1] ul li[3] {}
 html body div[2] div[1] ul li[3] a {}
 html body div[2] div[1] ul li[4] {}
 html body div[2] div[1] ul li[4] a {}
 html body div[2] div[1] ul li[5] {}
 html body div[2] div[1] ul li[5] a {}
div.main {}
 html body div[2] div[2] h2 {}
 html body div[2] div[2] p {}
div.footer {}
 html body div[3] p {}
```

I tried to manipulate as much as possible, but couldn't get any better. Can you people help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Forked from [Perry Tew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364754/perry-tew)'s Code. Tried my best! :)

Taking a fork from [Perry Tew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364754/perry-tew), I have done something similar, which:

1. Works with both `Class` and `ID`.
2. Classes to be given using concatenated `.`s.
3. Gives `ID` the first preference, then `Class`.
4. Added spaces before `{`. <kbd>minor</kbd>

#### PHP Code:

```
<?php

function print_css($parentTag, $prefix, &$dup_checker) {
    if ($parentTag->nodeName == '#text') {
        return;
    }
    if ($parentTag->hasAttribute("class") || $parentTag->hasAttribute("id")) {
        $idpart = ($parentTag->hasAttribute("id")) ? "#" . $parentTag->getAttribute("id") : "";
        $classpart = ($parentTag->hasAttribute("class")) ? "." . str_replace(" ", ".", $parentTag->getAttribute("class")) : "";
        $my_css = $prefix . $parentTag->nodeName . $idpart . $classpart;
    } else {
        $my_css = $prefix . $parentTag->nodeName;
    }

    if (!isset($dup_checker[$my_css])) {
        echo $my_css . " {}\n";
        if ($parentTag->nodeName == 'a') {
            foreach (array("link", "visited", "hover", "active", "focus") as $pseudo)
                echo $my_css . ':' . $pseudo . " {}\n";
        }
        $dup_checker[$my_css] = 1;
    }

    $nodes = $parentTag->childNodes;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
        $node = $nodes->item($i);
        print_css($node, $my_css . ' ', $dup_checker);
    }
}

header('Content-type: text/plain');
$source = '<body class="theme">
    <div class="header class2">
        <h1><a href="#">Welcome</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li id="hellos" class="meow wuff"><a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <h2>Main Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p id="hello">Copyright &copy; 2012 Me!</p>
    </div>
</body>';
$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->loadHTML($source);
$nodes = $html->getElementsByTagName("body");
$css = "";
$dup_checker = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodes->item($i);
    print_css($node, '', $dup_checker);
}
?>
```

#### Output:

```
body.theme {}
body.theme div.header.class2 {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a:link {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a:visited {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a:hover {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a:active {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a:focus {}
body.theme div.content {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:link {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:visited {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:hover {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:active {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:focus {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a:link {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a:visited {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a:hover {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a:active {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a:focus {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a span {}
body.theme div.content div.main {}
body.theme div.content div.main h2 {}
body.theme div.content div.main p {}
body.theme div.footer {}
body.theme div.footer p#hello {}
```

#### Note:

When the `a` tag is a parent of `span` tag or some other tag, it doesn't print out the `pseudo` classes. Can anyone help me revise the code?

#### Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/UbBil2 (Old One)

#### Initial credits should go to [Perry Tew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364754/perry-tew).

Comment: the multiple classes concatenation is a nice improvement.

Comment: Need to check all the conditions. Can you also include the :hover and :link which was done by @PerryTew? So that I can mark this answer.

Comment: When the `a` tag is a parent of `span` tag or some other tag, it doesn't print out the `pseudo` classes. Can anyone help me revise the code?

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to learn php by answering questions.  The code below appears to generate the output you're looking for.  I would love feedback and criticism on any mistakes I've made.  Thanks!

```
<?php

    function print_css($parent_node, $prefix, &$dup_checker){
      if($parent_node->nodeName == '#text'){
        return;
      }
      if ($parent_node->hasAttribute("id")) {
        $my_css = $prefix . $parent_node->nodeName . "#" . $parent_node->getAttribute("id");
      } elseif ($parent_node->hasAttribute("class")) {
          $my_css = $prefix . $parent_node->nodeName . "." . $parent_node->getAttribute("class");
      } else {
          $my_css = $prefix . $parent_node->nodeName;
      }

      if(!isset($dup_checker[$my_css])){
        echo $my_css . " {}\n";
        if($parent_node->nodeName =='a'){
          echo $my_css . ':link' . " {}\n";
          echo $my_css . ':visited' . " {}\n";
          echo $my_css . ':hover' . " {}\n";
          echo $my_css . ':active' . " {}\n";
          echo $my_css . ':focus' . " {}\n";
        }
        $dup_checker[$my_css] = 1;
      }

      $nodes = $parent_node->childNodes;
      for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
        $node = $nodes->item($i);
        print_css($node, $my_css . ' ', $dup_checker);
      }
    }

    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    $source = '<body class="theme">
        <div class="header">
            <h1><a href="#">Welcome</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li id="fourth_id"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li id="fifth_id"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <h2>Main Heading</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2012 Me!</p>
        </div>
    </body>';
    $html = new DOMDocument;
    $html->loadHTML($source);
    $nodes = $html->getElementsByTagName("body");
    $css = "";
    $dup_checker = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
      $node = $nodes->item($i);
      print_css($node, '', $dup_checker);
    }

    ?>

Output:
body.theme {}
body.theme div.header {}
body.theme div.header h1 {}
body.theme div.header h1 a {}
body.theme div.header h1 a:link {}
body.theme div.header h1 a:visited {}
body.theme div.header h1 a:hover {}
body.theme div.header h1 a:active {}
body.theme div.header h1 a:focus {}
body.theme div.content {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:link {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:visited {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:hover {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:active {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:focus {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fourth_id {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fourth_id a {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fourth_id a:link {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fourth_id a:visited {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fourth_id a:hover {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fourth_id a:active {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fourth_id a:focus {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fifth_id {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fifth_id a {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fifth_id a:link {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fifth_id a:visited {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fifth_id a:hover {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fifth_id a:active {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#fifth_id a:focus {}
body.theme div.content div.main {}
body.theme div.content div.main h2 {}
body.theme div.content div.main p {}
body.theme div.footer {}
body.theme div.footer p {}
```

Comment: Oh, the only additional css rule it outputs compared to your desired output is "body.theme{}", but I thought that would be a valid rule as well, so I didn't code it out.

Comment: Let me check and let you know!

Comment: Awesome! Can you make the same for the `ID` too? i.e., when something like `<p id="hi">` is there, it should return as `p#hi`.

Comment: I think so.  What behavior would you like if the element contains both an id and a class? Would you like both outputted?  Or should the id take precedence over the class and only output the id in the rule?

Comment: Might also be worth iterating through the various pseudo-selector styles for the `a` elements (`a:link`, `a:visited`, `a:hover`, `a:active`, `a:focus`).

Comment: @PerryTew I just forked your code to make my answer. Is it fine? But since I know CSS, I have made some good enhancements. Check out my answer.

Comment: David, I added in the pseudo elements as you suggested.  It's easy enough to comment out if undesired.

Comment: Actually, yeah, @PerryTew Teh pseudo elements are good, but will it be fine if people do not wanna use it? I mean, sometimes, they need to club the `:link, :active, :visited`. Just a case... :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  it supports IDs and eliminates duplicates and can treat some elements to be shown only once instead of li[1] li[2]

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$source = '<body class="theme">
    <div class="header">
        <h1><a href="#">Welcome</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="ff">
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li id="hh"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <h2>Main Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2012 Me!</p>
    </div>
</body>';
$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->loadHTML($source);
$nodes = $html->getElementsByTagName("*");
$css = array();
$paths=array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodes->item($i);
    $key=$node->getNodePath();

    if(!$node->hasAttribute("class") && !$node->hasAttribute("id"))


        $paths=addPath($paths,$key,"",$node->nodeName);
        $path=process($paths,$key);
        if (!$path)continue;
        $css[$key]=str_replace(array("/"), array(" "), $path) . " {}\n";
    if ($node->hasAttribute("class")) {
        $class=$node->nodeName . "." . $node->getAttribute("class");

        $paths=addPath($paths,$key,$class,$node->nodeName);
        $path=process($paths,$key);

        $css[$key]=str_replace(array("/"), array(" "), $path) . " {}\n";
    } elseif ($node->hasAttribute("id")) {
        $id="#" . $node->getAttribute("id");
        $paths=addPath($paths,$key,$id,$node->nodeName);
        $path=process($paths,$key);

        $css[$key]=str_replace(array("/"), array(" "), $path) . " {}\n";
    }
}

$css=implode("",array_unique($css));
echo $css;

function addPath($paths,$path,$class,$name){

    $once_elems=array(
        'li','a'
    );

    $sourcePath=explode("/",$path);
    if ($sourcePath[1]=="html"){
        unset($sourcePath[1]);
    }
    $path=implode("/",$sourcePath);

    if (!$class && isset($paths[$path])){
        return $paths;
    }

    if ((in_array($name,$once_elems) && !$class) || !$class){
        $class=$name;
    }

    $paths[$path]=$class;
    return $paths;
}

function process($paths,$path){
    $sourcePath=explode("/",$path);
    if ($sourcePath[1]=="html"){
        unset($sourcePath[1]);
    }
    $sourcePath=array_values($sourcePath);
    $path=implode("/",$sourcePath);
    foreach ($paths as $k=>$v){
        if (!$k)continue;
        $ex=explode("/",$k);

        if (strpos($path,$k,0)!==false){
            $sourcePath[count($ex)-1]=$v;
        }
    }
    $path=implode("/",$sourcePath);

    return $path;
}


?>
```

Output:

```
 body.theme {}
 body.theme div.header {}
 body.theme div.header h1 {}
 body.theme div.header h1 a {}
 body.theme div.content {}
 body.theme div.content #ff {}
 body.theme div.content div.sidebar {}
 body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul {}
 body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul #hh {}
 body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul #hh a {}
 body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li {}
 body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a {}
 body.theme div.content div.main {}
 body.theme div.content div.main h2 {}
 body.theme div.content div.main p {}
 body.theme div.footer {}
 body.theme div.footer p {}
```